# Sitecore Index_Update Job Performance

Tags: solr, publishing, indexing

We just updated from Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 to Update 7 and we've started seeing some strange behavior when publishing new items.

The issue presents itself in that it takes awhile for newly created items take awhile to show up on the site after they are published. It turns out that they publish just fine, but it takes awhile for them to be indexed so that the Item Resolver can find them.

After turning on a bunch of logging, I have determined that when you publish, the `Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_web_index` job runs right away as it should. If you publish JUST the new item, the job runs quickly and finishes quickly and the item will display.

If, however, you publish related item, the update job takes quite awhile to finish and the new item doesn't show up until the job finishes. This is true EVEN if you are doing a smart publish and only a couple items are updated.

In my testing I am working on a test environment that does not have much use. When I smart publish, only 3 items are updated, but it takes 6-7 minutes and my crawling log shows nearly 3000 items indexed following that one publish.

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this. The publish works, the index job kicks off as expected. There are no relevant errors logged (as far as I can tell). The indexing job finishes normally and the content is properly indexed after the job finishes running. It just seems like the indexing job is processing many more items than are necessary based on what was actually published.

I've tried truncating the EventQueue and PublishingQueue to be sure there isn't any data hanging around and it has not made any difference.

We are using SOLR indexes. Does anyone know of anything else to look at?

---

UPDATE 1 (as requested in the comments):
Update strategy is `onPublishEndAsync` and that strategy is configured with `CheckForThreshold` set to `true`.

There is no `Indexing.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold` (or any `FullRebuildItemCountThreshold` for that matter) defined in any config. According to the documentation, this value will default to 100,000.

---

UPDATE 2 (as requested in the comments):
There are no custom publishing pipelines except a couple that log extra data for the current publish item.  There are none that publish extra items.

As for the extra debugging, here is what I see after turning it on. The publish log shows:

```
6812 14:23:00 INFO  Finished [Publishing] - ProcessQueue in 6793 ms
6812 14:23:00 INFO  Publish Mode : SingleItem
6812 14:23:00 INFO  Created : 0
6812 14:23:00 INFO  Updated : 128
6812 14:23:00 INFO  Deleted : 0
6812 14:23:00 INFO  Skipped : 12
```

The crawling log shows the following (I've removed interleaved updates of other indexes to just include the one in question, sitecore_web_index):

```
9884 14:23:00 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy executing.
9884 14:23:00 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy: Batch for processing [9315374; 9315501] Count: 128
9884 14:23:00 DEBUG IndexCustodian. IncrementalUpdate triggered on index sitecore_web_index. Data=Count=128
10624 14:23:33 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 500 out of 500 - solr status: 0
10624 14:23:58 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 500 out of 500 - solr status: 0
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:24:22 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 500 out of 500 - solr status: 0
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:24:44 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 500 out of 500 - solr status: 0
4644 14:25:04 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 500 out of 500 - solr status: 0
10624 14:25:30 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 500 out of 500 - solr status: 0
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:25:43 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Documents sent to SOLR: 320 out of 320 - solr status: 0
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:25:43 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Committing: Add: 3320; Update:0; DeleteUnique: 85; DeleteGroup: 0
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:25:43 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Committed - solr status 0
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:25:43 DEBUG IndexDependentHtmlCacheManager triggered.
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:25:43 DEBUG IndexDependentHtmlCacheManager done (processed sites: 16).
```

The header of the crawling job reports 128 items in the batch (which matches the number of items published), but the job actually ends up sending 3320 updates to SOLR. Many of the 128 items in the batch are related items (templates and layouts) but almost all of the 3320 items sent to SOLR are content which is why filtering the indexing to just the content items will not have much of an effect on the issue.

Comment: The thing is that for the default web index, most of the item will be indexed as the root is set from the /Content. What you can do is to create a custom index configuration file so that it indexes only items and fields that you require. This should decrease the time taken when indexes are being refreshed

Comment: I had considered this, but I have the logging adjusted to log the index updates being made and all of the items being logged are already in the /Content portion of the tree so it would not seem to be the root of my problem.

Comment: Is this only happening for the sitecore_web_index? Are other indexes fine?

Comment: Yes, this is only the web index.  When I watch the Job Viewer and the logs, only the web index update job fires up and hangs around for awhile.

Comment: @BenStichter Since this is the web database index, can you check on a few settings and add them here? 1. <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold> 2. Indexing.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold ? 

I have faced similar issues before and they turned out to be threshold related. For reference - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies

Comment: @Gabbar, I had checked these settings already and am pretty sure they were ok, but I will dig them up again to be sure and will add them to the question above.

Comment: @BenStichter .. can you try to turn on detailed crawling logs by changing the following setting to "DEBUG" temporarily ? <logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Crawling" additivity="false" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config">
<level value="INFO"/>
<appender-ref ref="SearchLogFileAppender"/>
</logger>

Also check to see if there is any special process in the publish pipelines that might be triggering extra items publish like related items or child items.

Comment: @Gabbar, I've already cranked up the crawling settings (which is why I know several thousand items are being crawled), but honestly, I'm not sure it was to this level because your setting doesn't look familiar.  I'll revisit the setting with your recommendation and see if it uncovers anything.  As for the publish pipelines, good point, will investigate this as well.

Comment: @Gabbar, I posted my findings above. I also added the filter you asked about in your first post and it had basically no effect. The number of items reported sent to SOLR dropped from 3320 to 3000, but the process still ran for along time.  I'm pretty sure the issue is the whole 3000ish documents being sent when only 128 were published.

Comment: @BenStichter .. i don't see any relevant information. Do you have any computed fields that are being pushed to Solr?

Comment: @Gabbar, almost certainly... I'll have to research further next week!

Comment: @Gabbar, we do have 8 computed fields being pushed to SOLR using the IComputedIndexField functionality. These have been around for quite awhile from even before the upgrade and do not seem to be affecting the over all performance significantly. In the logs above, the throughput of 500 items per 20-30 seconds doesn't seem unusual. Does this seem unusually slow to you?